# Qt Qml How to set the value of the QSG_INFO parameter to 1

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I got stuck with the problem that my application on some PCs loads the processor very heavily, and does not load the video card at all. When I went to figure it out, I came across this article: https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/01/18/opengl-implementation-qt-quick-app-using-today

It describes the method of debugging, and says that it is necessary to set the value of the environment QSG_INFO = 1. Current I do not quite understand where it needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an environment variable you can use [`qputenv()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qputenv):

```cpp
#include <QtGlobal>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    qputenv("QSG_INFO", "1");
    
    QGuiApplication a(argv, argc); 
    // ...
```

or you can set when launching the executable:

```
QSG_INFO=1 ./your_executable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application from Qt Creator you can add/overwrite environment variables from the Project tab:

[image: Qt creator environment variable editor]

Look at this [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-settings-environment.html) for more info.